# FFT from libraries have lower levels than Web audio FFT

Tags: signal-processing, fft, web-audio-api

I am trying to graph FFT from microphone input in the web browser. I created an object that plots the FFT result into a canvas. I first used the frequency data of a web audio analyzer (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteFrequencyData) and got the plot that appears in black. It detects considerable levels for most frequencies until nearly 0.5 per sample. First graph is the FFT and the second is the captured microphone noise.

[image: plot of web audio api analyzer fft]

Later I did exactly the same, this time using fft.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/fft.js). The resulting FFT looks barely populated, even though I have expanded the vertical axis (top left number is the maximum value in the graph)

[image: FFt graph that looks barely populated]

I feel that there is a concept that I am missing out, and I would like to know: why the two FFT's have such different results? Do I need to shape the input or the output from a scale to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be comparing apples and oranges here.  According to the [spec for `getByteFrequencyData`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-analysernode-getbytefrequencydata), the values you get are on a dB scale.

The values from the FFT library are probably linear. If so, you'll need to convert that to dB before comparing results. (Or convert the byte frequency data to linear).

Note also, that WebAudio applies a windowing function before computing the result. This will probably make it different from your FFT result unless you also apply the same windowing function.

Comment: Thanks! that's just what I needed to start my search.

Comment: Good luck, and let us know what the problem was.  Oh, BTW, you might want to use `getFloatFrequencyData` instead of `getByteFrequencyData` to make it easier to compare with your FFT library.

Comment: I think the difference was, as you say, scale. I suspect that there's compensation for acoustic perception of volume across tones aswell.

Comment: Not in the AnalyserNode. It's pretty basic: window the signal, apply the FFT, take the magnitude and return it. (Well, some averaging of FFTs over time can happen too).  But no acoustic perception.